# Jquery Autocompletes with long list of suggestions showing up when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete 
My code for autocomplete as below.

```
var options, a;
jQuery(function(){
options = { serviceUrl:'/getEmployee'};
a = $('#autocomplete').autocomplete(options);
});
```

My serviceUrl will give a long json data as below

```
{"suggestions": [
"",
"AAHM@X.COM",
"AAKBHAGYALAXMI@X.COM",
"JOHNFAH@X.COM",
"ABDURREHMAN.L@X.COM",
// UP TO 1000++ records
]}
```

HTML code

```
<input type="text" name="q" id="autocomplete" />
```

List of suggestions is showing up and appear in scrollable list, CSS make it the word gets underline.

However when I start typing, the not relevant one doesnt get removed from the list. Hence all those 1000++ records still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter this server side.

It is not well documented on the site, but this plug-in passes the URL parameter `query` to the server every time a letter is typed. e.g.

```
/getEmployee?query=John
```

So you can filter the list of email addresses server side using the query parameter and only return those that match the query.

You *could* download all the email addresses and filter client-side but it **will** download the 1000+ records to the page every time the page loads:

```
 $.getJSON('/getEmployee', function(data) {
    var fullList = data.suggestions;
    options = { lookup: fullList };
    a = $('#autocomplete').autocomplete(options);
 });
```